# What to do with out of date question with no answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, end-of-life

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319116/how-to-install-qt3-runtime-library-in-ubuntu-13-04) was on topic and not a terrible question when it was asked. But it has received not answers, and is now off topic.

Just want to make sure I'm correct in thinking this should be closed. But I'm not really sure of a good flag reason.

In general should unanswered question about out-of-date releases be closed?

Comment: Just one remark: old questions about *now* unsupported releases don't become off-topic.

Comment: Agreed. Its not off-topic, but its also not useful. So whats a good close reason for questions like this?

Comment: @ElderGeek See Jorge's comment below: offtopic->not reproducible

Answer (score 9):

Yes, if no one cares about it and it's just sitting there unanswered, let's get rid of it, I voted to close.

Comment: What reasoning does one give for closing such questions?

Comment: I usually do offtopic -> Can't be reproduced/relevant for only a specific period of time.

Comment: @JorgeCastro So end of life isn't a good reason for those unanswered, now unsupported questions? (this may explain why a large number of my flagged posts regarding 13.04 are in limbo)..

Comment: I don't think the flag reason will matter, it's either EOL or it's obviously abandoned; the close queue has nearly 1000 items in it, so they're not exactly in limbo, we just haven't got to them yet, keep em coming!

Comment: @JorgeCastro Ok. Staffing problem. That explains a lot, I will keep 'em coming and at some point help clean them up!

Comment: @JorgeCastro through VtC'ing seems the Right Thing To Do™, a single downvote in a 30 days old question prompts the Roomba to delete the question. Just saying.

Comment: @Briam What's a Roomba?

Comment: Please **don't vote EOL on old questions**! It makes it hard on reviewers that then need to tell if the question was version specific, how old, ect. Plus I just spent tons of time in the review queue sorting through questions that would otherwise get deleted automatically ~