# Why does "Community" bump years-old questions about now-obsolete versions to homepage?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231382/with-kernel-3-5-0-21-the-wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-stop-working) was just bumped to homepage (appr. 14:30 EDT 2018-05-21).  It's About an EOL LTS version that lost support years ago, specific to a kernel version that's a whole generation older (3.x versus current 4.x) than what we have now.  If this were asked new now, it would be instantly closed as off topic due to unsupported Ubuntu version.  What's gained by having questions like this remain live on the site?

Comment: Note that [12.04 is still supported in line with the extended security maintenance for costumers](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life).

Comment: @dessert "Extended Security Maintenance" doesn't include any help making your 2010 wifi hardware work...

Answer (score 5):

The Community user's choice amongst potential bumping candidates is pretty random, I assume.

> posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed). <sub>[[Source]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/280883)</sub>

Beyond that, and the number of views as a weighting factor, the Community user has no means to evaluate the usefulness of a particular question. It's an automated system with limited intelligence.

Comment: But we're not supposed to vote to close or flag questions like this, as I understand it.  Randomness of bumps accepted, what's gained by not closing or even deleting questions too old to have any utility for users of supported versions?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Have  a look at e.g. https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/10448/367990

Comment: The problem I see with leaving old questions about old versions is that they clutter up the "similar" sidebar when someone is trying to write a new question about the current version.  I've had a round dozen show, and none of them were even supported versions, never mind the version I was asking about.

Comment: @ZeissIkon we can certainly close and delete such questions if they have no useful answers and are unanswerable with the current information.